# AngularJS 1.3, ngAnimate and animate.css

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

Noob here :)
Trying to set an ngAnimation which basically works fine except for one annoying thing.
When the page loads the ng-hide animation is running.

How can i prevent this from happening?

Here is the code:
html:

```
<form name="signup_form" novalidate>

                <!-- USERNAME -->
                <label class="item item-input ">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" ng-model="newUser.username" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" ng-minlength=4 ng-maxlength=20  required/>
                </label>
                <div class="error" ng-show="signup_form.username.$dirty && signup_form.username.$invalid">
                    <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.username.$error.required">Username is required.</small>
                    <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.username.$error.minlength">Your name is required to be at least 4 characters</small>
                    <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.username.$error.maxlength">Your name cannot be longer than 20 characters</small>
                </div>
```

Here is the css

```
.error {
    color: #F00;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    text-align: center;
}

.error.ng-show {
    -webkit-animation: bounceIn 1s;
    -moz-animation: bounceIn 1s;
    -ms-animation: bounceIn 1s;
    animation: bounceIn 1s;
}
.error.ng-hide {
    -webkit-animation: bounceOut 1s;
    -moz-animation: bounceOut 1s;
    -ms-animation: bounceOut 1s;
    animation: bounceOut 1s;
}
```

Also tried using the ng-cloak directive but it did not help.
Would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you try to replicate it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/KpmXZICh1MSzyPTNPEW5?p=preview

Comment: I tried and could not :(, i am using ionic as a base for this app, should this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Since i could not find the reason, i started from scratch and it worked fine. 
Don't really know what happened.